# How to find all schemas where a table has records?

Tags: oracle, select, view

In my Oracle database, I have a number of schemas (users/owners) with similar table structures (about 100 in total). However, some tables are empty in a lot of schemas. Is there a way to find out for which schemas a table (with a particular name, which will be the same across all the queried schemas) has records/rows?

Is there a view in Oracle which contains all records? For example, if I am looking for columns, I can search ALL_TAB_COLUMNS; if I am searching for tables, I can look in DBA_TABLES or ALL_OBJECTS. Is there an equivalent for records?

This would also be helpful for another query - to find all tables (of a given name) across all schemas, where a particular field has a non-null value in at least one record.

Answer (score 2):

DBA_TABLES.NUM_ROWS column can be used to identify tables that are empty. But this column is updated by DBMS_STATS, so it is not 100% accurate.

There is no view that contains all records.

Comment: Note: From Oracle version 10g DBMS_STATS will be executed automatically but it may take some hours until a new table would be analyzed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no table or view that is the equivalent for records.
You could achieve this by generating dynamic SQL in a PL/SQL script to produce selects against each table and then run each generated SQL using 'execute immediate'.
Unfortunately I don't have the time to write up a quick script at the minute as I'm still at work.

Comment: This is probably the slowest method. If you choose do this, check http://laurentschneider.com/wordpress/2007/04/how-do-i-store-the-counts-of-all-tables.html, it could be helpful.

Comment: @Raj. Thanks for that link. I'll have a play around with that type of method when I get 5 minutes

Comment: This answer is not correct. Refer to what sjk wrote.

Comment: Not sure why a downvote as what I have said is certainly possible and would satisfy the OP requirement. The answer by sjk does not seem to indicate why my answer is incorrect.